# How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got fresh install of Apache 2.2 on my Vista machine, everything works fine, except mod rewrite.

I've uncommented

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.s
```

but none of my rewrite rules works, even simple ones like

```
RewriteRule not_found %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php?page=404
```

All the rules I'm using are working on my hosting, so they should be ok, so my question is, is there any hidden thing in apache configuration, that could block mod rewrite?

Comment: actually the problem was that i had wrong path, because ${DOCUMENT_ROOT} pointed me to root directory which was ok on hosting, but wrong on local, so the problem wasnt just RewriteEngine On, which i already had ..

Comment: Can you please change the accepted answer to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5758551/447356)? The author of current accepted answer has admitted it's not good enough.

Comment: [How to enable mod_rewrite in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (should work in Debian too)](http://www.dev-metal.com/enable-mod_rewrite-ubuntu-12-04-lts/). This shows installation AND activation, the tutorials below surprisingly don't do :(

Comment: I would strongly advise everybody that wants to enable mod_rewrite directives in .htacces files to use `AllowOverride FileInfo` instead of allowing everything, as ALL the answers on this page suggest. Sad to see all these answers take the as-long-as-it-works-it's-okay-approach instead of trying to understand the consequences of the proposed 'solution'. Try to understand what you are doing on your server and how to limit the privileges you just gave away with `AllowOverride All`. [RTFM!](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride), it is quit clear on the subject.

Comment: Where did you uncommented it? Where is the file?

Comment: @Black It's in the Apache config file named httpd.conf. In my PC, it is in the directory C:\xampp\apache\conf, because I installed Apache with XAMPP.

Answer (score 1137, accepted):

In order to use `mod_rewrite` you can type the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart apache2 after

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or as per new unified System Control Way

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Then, if you'd like, you can use the following `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The above `.htaccess` file (if placed in your `DocumentRoot`) will redirect all traffic to an `index.php` file in the `DocumentRoot` unless the file exists.

So, let's say you have the following directory structure and httpdocs is the `DocumentRoot`

```
httpdocs/
    .htaccess
    index.php
    images/
        hello.png
    js/
        jquery.js
    css/
        style.css
includes/
    app/
        app.php
```

Any file that exists in httpdocs will be served to the requester using the `.htaccess` shown above, however, everything else will be redirected to `httpdocs/index.php`. Your application files in `includes/app` will not be accessible.

Comment: The ideas here are correct for a UNIX CLI but the commands only work for a Debian based Linux distributions and not a Windows environment of the OP.

Comment: a2enmod rewrite did the job

Comment: Further note: you also need to make sure that your site's configuration has `AllowOverride All` in order for the `.htaccess` file to be read at all.

Comment: How do you turn mod_rewrite off, in other words, reverse the action by `a2enmod rewrite`?

Comment: @Dennis you can use a2dismod rewrite

Comment: Use `AllowOverride FileInfo` rather than `All` in your site-configuration if you don't need to allow any other overrides.

Comment: @Lamy /etc/init.d/httpd restart works with Redhat based systems and old apache versions

Comment: how to do it in online project?

Comment: how can I use `a2enmod rewrite` in windows?

Comment: This is the best answer to a totally different question, found when I googled "debian install mod rewrite"

Comment: What change needs to be made to make includes/app as accessible?

Comment: I also referred to this https://askubuntu.com/questions/833040/how-to-enable-clean-url-with-ubuntu-16-04-drupal-8-1-10-and-apache-2

Comment: is the command essential or can it be done purely from a conf file?

Answer (score 247):

For my situation, I had

```
RewriteEngine On
```

in my `.htaccess`, along with the module being loaded, and it was not working.

The solution to my problem was to edit my vhost entry to inlcude

```
AllowOverride all
```

in the `<Directory>` section for the site in question.

Comment: Indeed, even with `a2enmod rewrite` & `RewriteEngine On` in the `.htaccess` - the existence of `AllowOverride all` in the VirtualHost file will prevent it from working - this is what caught me out, changing it to `AllowOverride all` worked like a charm :)

Comment: beginner here.. where's the VirtualHost file ?

Comment: THIS is the way to go... I had everything else set except for this.

Comment: The `AllowOverride` directive determines the "Types of directives that are allowed in `.htaccess` files". Furthermore, "When this directive is set to `None`, then `.htaccess` files are completely ignored. In this case, the server will not even attempt to read `.htaccess` files in the filesystem." Official docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: This fixed it for me -- I had an issue with WordPress pretty permalinks not working properly. If you do `a2enmod rewrite`and then in the VirtualHosts file change 'AllowOverride None' to 'AllowOverride All' it should work. The VirtualHosts file applies if you are running multiple domain names to the same server (and IP address). You would have set it up to set up the domain.

Comment: in what file should I include "AllowOverride all" I'm testing this in my personal computer running ubuntu and apache, but eventually I want to upload to share hosting thanks?

Comment: In Ubuntu, the path is /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Answer (score 97):

Try setting: `AllowOverride All`.

---

Second most common issue is not having mod rewrite enabled: `a2enmod rewrite` and then restart apache.

Comment: This should be the #1 answer as it solves a problem that is happening in a default ubuntu installation!

Comment: This will allow .htaccess to override any other apache configuration. This is not recommended.

Comment: Yes :) this was my problem too, but here is the place that you are explaining for rookies like me that this "AllowOverride All" is in /etc/apache2/sites-available/[sitename].conf and [sitename-ssl].conf.
I had to do a second research because of you :D, thanks by the way!

Answer (score 92):

If non of the above works try editing /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

almost at the top you will find

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Change the `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

this worked for me

Comment: Changed error from `/laravel/public/authors was not found on this server` to `/index.php was not found on this server`

Comment: cant find < Directory >, only <VirtualHost *:80>

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu place this in the <VirtualHost *:80> tag

Comment: I've done the same but added a new section `<Directory /var/www/html>` to apply the rule from this folder and up only.

Answer (score 59):

New apache version has change in some way. If your apache version is 2.4 then you have to go to `/etc/apache2/`. There will be a file named `apache2.conf`. You have to edit that one(you should have root permission). Change directory text like this

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Now restart apache.

```
service apache2 reload
```

Hope it works.

Comment: This is the up to date answer.

Comment: If you are in 2019 and beyond, please upvote this answer :)

Comment: Yes sir, this helped me out of a jam! Simplest of all answers.

Answer (score 49):

In Ubuntu:

Run:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

and then:

```
service apache2 restart
```

`mod_rewrite` will now be enabled!

Answer (score 35):

There are many ways how you can fix this issue, if you know the root of the issue.

**Problem 1**

Firstly, it may be a problem with your apache not having the mod_rewrite.c module installed or enabled.

For this reason, you would have to  enable it as follows

1. Open up your console and type into it, this:

   `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
2. Restart your apache server.

   `service apache2 restart`

**Problem 2**

1. You may also, in addition to the above, if it does not work, have to change the override rule from the apache conf file (either apache2.conf, http.conf , or 000-default file).
2. Locate "Directory /var/www/"
3. Change the "Override None" to "Override All"

**Problem 3**

If you get an error stating rewrite module is not found, then probably your userdir module 
is not enabled. For this reason you need to enable it.

1. Type this into the console:

   `sudo a2enmod userdir`
2. Then try enabling the rewrite module if still not enabled (as mentioned above).

To read further on this, you can visit this site: http://seventhsoulmountain.blogspot.com/2014/02/wordpress-permalink-ubuntu-problem-solutions.html

Comment: Great breakdown of the issue.

Comment: Don't use `AllowOverride All` as it will enable too many dangerours features (like using perl scripts). Instead use `AllowOveride Options`

Answer (score 33):

Open  terminal and typin `a2enmod rewrite`, It will enable your `mod_rewrite` module for Apache.

Then go to `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and edit default file. (For this you must have writable permissions to this file and sites-available folder.)

Replace below with existing lines 4 to 14

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now restart your apache by `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` or `service apache2 restart`

Take clean URL test again and this time it will be passed.

Answer (score 15):

**<edit>**

Just noticed you said mod_rewrite.s instead of mod_rewrite.so - hope that's a typo in your question and not in the httpd.conf file! :)

**</edit>**

I'm more used to using Apache on Linux, but I had to do this the other day.

First off, take a look in your Apache install directory. (I'll be assuming you installed it to "C:\Program Files" here)

Take a look in the folder: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\modules" and make sure that there's a file called mod_rewrite.so in there. (It should be, it's provided as part of the default install.

Next, open up "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf" and open httpd.conf. Make sure the line:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

is uncommented:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Also, if you want to enable the RewriteEngine by default, you might want to add something like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite>
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
```

to the end of your httpd.conf file.

If not, make sure you specify

```
RewriteEngine On
```

somewhere in your .htaccess file.

Comment: @gabehabe your avatar just just looked like it was holding an icon my doc , lol

Answer (score 10):

Use below command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And the restart apache through below command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 8):

I just did this

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

then you have to restart the apache service by following command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 7):

Old thread, just want to put that don't set AllowOverride to all instead use specific mod you want to use,

```
AllowOverride mod_rewrite mod_mime
```

And this line should be un-commented

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Refrences

- http://www.eschrade.com/page/why-you-should-not-use-htaccess-allowoverride-all-in-production/
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/security_tips.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html

Answer (score 4):

The first time I struggled with mod_rewrite rules ignoring my traffic, I learned (frustratingly) that I had placed them in the wrong `<VirtualHost>`, which meant that my traffic would ignore **all** of them no matter how well-written they were. Make sure this isn't happening to you:

`# Change the log location to suit your system.
RewriteLog /var/log/apache-rw.log
RewriteLogLevel 2`

These parameters will activate if you perform a graceful restart of Apache, so you can recycle them in and closely monitor the mod_rewrite behavior. Once your problem is fixed, turn the RewriteLogLevel back down and celebrate.

In 100% of my experience, I've found that the RewriteLog has helped me discover the problem with my rewrite rules. I can't recommend this enough. Good luck in your troubleshooting!

Also, this bookmark is your best friend:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: This was removed and is no longer available in 2.4 (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 3):

There's obviously more than one way to do it, but I would suggest using the more standard:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=404
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me (in ubuntu):

```
sudo su
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
ln ../mods-available/rewrite.load rewrite.load
```

Also, as already mentioned, make sure `AllowOverride all` is set in the relevant section of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`